# how to call table attribute specifically from database?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Im trying to do if else using Camp data in table testing_data. did i do this correctly in retrieve the data and calling it in if else..i really newbies in php ..hope you can help me..tq

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "brindley";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "SELECT * FROM testing_data";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


if($user["t_month"] === 'Q1')
{
    if($user['t_bbq'] === 'Kambing Golek')
    {
        if($user['t_participant'] =='>=21 to <=40')
        {
            if($user['t_outdoor'] == 'Tiada')
            {
                if($user['t_packages']== 'Pakej 4')
                {
                    echo "YES, People prefer choose packages like this";
                }
                else 
                {
                     echo "NO";
                }
            }
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: Clarify your question. What is your goal here?

Comment: my goal here is to compare the data from table testing_data with the value that i set in if else to know whether the data in table is preferable with the people usually choose